# IE 9 CSS Float problem!

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

The following web page is not showing properly in IE 9.

It seems to be only a problem in IE 9.

http://froyo.tv/test/

the list-style-image are over the image!

[image]

IE9

[image]

Firefox, Chrome, IE8, ...

**EDIT: I know how to fix it! But I want to know what is really going on with IE9**

Fixed: http://froyo.tv/test/index_fix.php

Comment: I know how to fix it. But ain't it a shame that MS has bring again compatibility problem

Comment: The test page still demonstrate the problem!. I have no idea why it showing like that only in IE9. But when I inspect with Firebug in Firefox, the list is really over the image, but display on the right.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why IE9 is behaving differently, but you can fix it to work consistently by:

- Removing `margin-right: 30px` on `.image`.
- Removing `width: 500px` on `.detail` *(you may wish to add back a smaller `width`)*
- **Adding `float: left` to `.detail`.**

---

Here's a simple reproduction of the problem.

- Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3kf/
- Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3kf/1/

Comment: I have already found how to fix it! It's a shame that I hav found a problem in IE9 only after minutes after install

Comment: Here my fix: http://froyo.tv/test/index_fix.php , It is basically the same as you. float:left on .detail seems to be the key

Comment: I agree that it's (probably!) an IE9 bug. I couldn't find a neater way to fix it than as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fix for the problem in IE9:

li{list-style-position: inside;}

I guess that IE9 doesn't have the list bullets "inside".

Se the fix here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3kf/40/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using Chrome I can see the custom list images, IE9 doesn't handle list-style-image.
Instead of using it, try this:
li {background:url(your_image.jpg) center left;}

Comment: IE9 does support list-style-image!! The appear over the left image