# Padding bug in iframe in Facebook app

Tags: css, layout, iframe, padding

First post from a lurker, so please bear with me.

In my company's Facebook app, there's a form that can have error messages, which are getting double left padding. They have a fair bit of padding to line up with the inputs above them (which also get the left padding).

[(Broken error message img) http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2609/windows7x64ie9beta2.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/2609/windows7x64ie9beta2.png)

When I pop this same page out of the Facebook iframe, it displays normally, with form elements and error messages lining up.

[(Non-broken error message img) http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/651/windows7x64ie9beta14.png](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/651/windows7x64ie9beta14.png)

The actual code is an inherited (in all senses of the word) mess, but does work in everything including IE6 & 7 with no hacks.  Here are all of the non-reset-styles on these lis:

```
clear: none;
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 160px;
```

I've confirmed that doubling the padding yields the messed up view (I can only use IE Developer tools in the non-messed up view since it can't handle the iframe).

Anyone have any idea?  Other than ripping up this old code and starting over?

UPDATE: Seems like ripping up the old code might be a necessity.  I have some ULs with no children that might be causing some breakage.

UPDATE 2: The dynamically generated dom is a mess, but the engineers here have no time to refactor it, so I may never get the answer to this question.  :(

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why not post the image on a third party server and link for now?

Comment: Thanks, Moshe - I will do that as soon as I get home.

Comment: @BethBudwig - I've made the images appear inline for you. I suggest you read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), so you know how reputation works. (There are no magic coins. ;D)

Comment: @Moshe - thanks for making the images appear inline.  Also, I was just joking about the coins.  ;)   *off to re-read FAQ*

Comment: @Beth -- my guess is you are missing an end tag (eg `</td>`) and the recovery is handled differently in the iframe because it does not have the surrounding elements.

Comment: I would love to see the actual source being generated for the iframe so we can verify what's going on, but maybe that's just me being silly...

Comment: @drachenstern - I'm sure that would solve the mystery quickly.  A screen shot is less than satisfactory when solving a problem like this.

Comment: @beth: Hey there! I agree with @drachenstern: please post the generated source code so we can take a look at what's being created.

Comment: @everyone Got it, I'll dive into the HTML and hunt for an unclosed tag.  As far as posting much code goes, not sure how my company feels about it... but I will if I can.

Comment: ...and y'all are right on.  Several uls with no lis may be causing the issue.  The code is generated deep somewhere so it will be a while before I can verify this theory.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an ideal solution, but I would use a condition and a separate IE9-only stylesheet to fix this issue.

Something like:

```
    <!--IF[IE 9]-->
      // Include IE9 stylesheet here
<![endif]-->
```

and in that stylesheet maybe do something like this:

```
clear: none;
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 80px; /* half the padding */
```

Comment: That's kind of my backup plan -- but it may be worth having a few messed up error messages for a while for 4% of our users to not have another IE specific stylesheet to maintain.  But it's a decent solution.  :)

Comment: Are you guys using any sort of reset? I know you mentioned that the styles weren't being reset, but it a reset stylesheet out of the question?

Comment: We're using a reset.  I listed the non-reset styles.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using floats? I reached this question via a similar problem.

Check out this answer: [IE 9 CSS Float problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359302/ie-9-css-float-problem)

Comment: I'm not using floats - sorry, I think it's unrelated!